# Plotting Date/Time Issue w/ Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have two dataframe to be used for a figure. The figure have two axes. Each axes will plot one of the dataframe data sets. The problem is that one of the axes plot the data and timepoint labels without problem while the other present a rare x data/time labels. Any help in what I am doing wrong?

The dataframe that giving me problems is taking the time data from a source file that once loaded to python I add the corresponding date prefix. Here a snapshot of those line codes:

```
thickDF['Time'] = thickDF['Time'].astype(str)

thickDF['DateTime'] = '2023-08-25 ' + thickDF['Time']
thickDF['DateTime'] = thickDF['DateTime'].astype(str)
thickDF['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(thickDF['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```
The output is the following 

 Index  Run    IPC  Value            DateTime
0       2    7  THICK   4.15 2023-08-25 08:14:57
1       2    7  THICK   4.13 2023-08-25 08:14:57
2       2    7  THICK   4.14 2023-08-25 08:14:57
3       2    7  THICK   4.09 2023-08-25 08:14:57
4       2    7  THICK   4.14 2023-08-25 08:14:57
.
.
```

The other data set output, which is not giving any problem is:

```
Date  Ejection Force [kN]  index
0   2023-08-25 08:10:55.000                407.0    0.0
1   2023-08-25 08:11:54.995                396.0    1.0
2   2023-08-25 08:12:54.995                377.0    2.0
3   2023-08-25 08:24:25.000                385.0    3.0
4   2023-08-25 08:25:25.000                372.0    4.0
..                      ...                  ...    ...
345 2023-08-25 19:48:06.000                299.0  345.0
346 2023-08-25 19:49:07.000                292.0  346.0
347 2023-08-25 19:50:06.000                281.0  347.0
348 2023-08-25 19:51:06.000                284.0  348.0
349 2023-08-25 19:52:06.000                285.0  349.0
```

Both DateTime column type are:

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

When I run the following code:

```
#Additional Libraries
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt

# Define the number of rows and columns in the grid
n_rows = 2
n_cols = 1

# Create a grid of subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n_rows, ncols=n_cols, figsize=(20, 8))

# Set a custom color palette with distinct colors
custom_palette = sns.color_palette("Set1", len(thickDF['DateTime'].unique()))

sns.stripplot(data=thickDF, x='DateTime', y='Value', palette=custom_palette, s=10, marker="$\circ$", zorder=-1, ax=axes[0])
sns.pointplot(data=thickDF, x="DateTime", y="Value", estimator=np.mean, join=False, ci=None, markers=['o'], color='k', ax=axes[0])
axes[1].plot_date(ejectionDF['Date'], ejectionDF["Ejection Force [kN]"], 'bo',  marker = '.', markersize='12', label='Force [kN]')


# Plot variables
axes[0].axis('on')
axes[1].axis('on')

## Axis Line Width
for axis in ['top','bottom','left', 'right']:
    axes[0].spines[axis].set_linewidth(2.0)
    axes[1].spines[axis].set_linewidth(2.0)

    
# X and Y ticks Formatting 
axes[0].tick_params(axis="y",direction="in")
axes[0].tick_params(axis="x",direction="in")
axes[1].tick_params(axis="y",direction="in")
axes[1].tick_params(axis="x",direction="in")


axes[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
axes[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))


# X and Y Axis Formatting
axes[0].set_ylim(4.0,4.2)
axes[1].set_ylim(200,500)


#axes[0].set_xlim([dt.datetime(2023,8,25,8,0,0), dt.datetime(2023,8,25,20,0,0)])
axes[1].set_xlim([dt.datetime(2023,8,25,8,0,0), dt.datetime(2023,8,25,20,0,0)])


#ax1.set_ylim(11,15)
axes[0].set_ylabel("Thickness [mm]",  fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
axes[1].set_ylabel("Force",  fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')


# Datetime Formatting
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
axes[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(8,20,1)))
axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
axes[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(8,20,1)))


axes[0].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90, pad=2.0, labelsize=14, length=0)
axes[1].tick_params(axis='y', direction='in', pad=2.0, labelsize=14, length=5)


# Title and Formatting 
fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=16,  y=0.97, fontweight='bold')


# Guidelines
axes[1].axvline(dt.datetime(2023,8,25,8,26,40), linestyle='--', c='r', label='Production Start')

# Legend Formatting
axes[0].legend(frameon=False, ncol=3, fontsize=10)
axes[1].legend(frameon=False, ncol=3, fontsize=10)


plt.tight_layout()

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

I get the following output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVUQ7.png)

I had try different data types (ex. str) without success, also trying to work it out with matplotlib only without success. Any help?